# changing button value according to filter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, html-table

New react(hooks) developer here, my question is related to updating the state when used filter,
here i have 5 buttons, two 'All' buttons, my point is when user clicks for example ' In Delivery' button then 'All' button which is under table should change its name(value) from 'All' to ' In Delivery', and same thing with others also 'Delivered', 'Order' and 'All' my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-surf-t9eh3?file=/src/Test.js:340-349

Comment: Please post code HERE (using the stack snippet) since links can go stale

Comment: anybody here to help ?

Comment: Any code here to look at???

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling setButtonText to actually change the text of that button... I this

```
function filterData(filter) {
    if (filter) {
      setButonText(filter)
      setFilteredEventsData(eventsData.filter((f) => f.key === filter));
    } else {
      setButonText("All");
      setFilteredEventsData(eventsData);
    }
  }
```

Comment: this is not actually doing it, you can try clicking 'In Delivery' button, it changes it into 'InDelivery', see buttons name is different, have another way ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your filterData function to this:

```
function filterData(filter) {
  if (filter) {
    setFilteredEventsData(eventsData.filter((f) => f.key === filter));
    setButonText(filter)
  } else {
    setFilteredEventsData(eventsData);
    setButonText("All")
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not actually doing it, you can try clicking 'In Delivery' button, it changes it into 'InDelivery', see buttons name is different